# Log4J Custom Fields

Tags: java, log4j

## Introduction:

I'm trying to get additional fields to log with log4j, and its working but only when I create an appender in code and not in the log4j.properties

## Progress:

1. Used this article [Adding Conversion Characters to PatternLayout](http://www.jajakarta.org/log4j/jakarta-log4j-1.1.3/docs/deepExtension.html) for log4j 1.1.3
2. Made a [sample app for log4j 1.2](http://github.com/scottcowan/spikes/tree/master/log4j/CustomFields/)

## Problem:

using the properties file it will run but won't use AppServerPatternLayout so the custom fields aren't displayed.

## [Download Code](http://github.com/scottcowan/spikes/tree/master/log4j/CustomFields/)

#### customlog.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=FATAL
log4j.logger.some.log=INFO,stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=logging.AppServerPatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=-----------------using log file------------------------%nTime:      %d%nHost:      %h%nServer:    %s%nComponent: %b%nVersion:   %v%nPriority:  %p%nThread Id: %t%nContext:   %x%nMessage:   %m%n
```

#### Main.java logging without a log4j properties file

```
AppServerLoggerFactory factory;
factory = new AppServerLoggerFactory("MyServer", "MyComponent", "1.0");
AppServerLogger.setFactory(factory);
Logger logger = AppServerLogger.getLogger("some.log");
PatternLayout layout = new AppServerPatternLayout( formatString );
logger.addAppender( new ConsoleAppender(layout) );
logger.info("Hello");
```

#### Main.java logging with a log4j properties file

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("customlog.properties");
AppServerLoggerFactory factory;
factory = new AppServerLoggerFactory("MyServer", "MyComponent", "1.0");
AppServerLogger.setFactory(factory);
Logger logger = AppServerLogger.getLogger("some.log");
logger.info("Hello");
```

#### Expected output

```
----------------using in code appender----------------------
Time:      2009-11-06 12:55:05,785
Host:      M1330
Server:    MyServer
Component: MyComponent
Version:   1.0
Priority:  INFO
Thread Id: main
Context:   
Message:   logging config from code
```

#### Actual output

```
-----------------using log file------------------------
Time:      2009-11-06 12:56:17,983
Host:      
Server:    
Component: 
Version:   
Priority:  INFO
Thread Id: main
Context:   
Message:   logging config from customlog.properties
```

## Solution

Using MDC you can add custom fields like

```
MDC.put("Version", versionName);
Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("some.log");        
log.info("Hello");
```

and pull it out in the log4j.properties with a UPPER case X

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%X{Version}
```

Comment: @RoeeGavirel https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the example you posted, I can only guess that `AppServerPatternLayout` is not in the package `logging`. Everything else looks find. Add

```
log4j.DEBUG=true
```

to your properties file. log4j will then dump what it does while reading the properties. Maybe that gives you an idea what's wrong.

If that doesn't help, consider to use [Nested Diagnostic Contexts](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Comment: looking at his github link, it is in the package: http://github.com/scottcowan/spikes/blob/master/log4j/CustomFields/src/logging/AppServerPatternLayout.java

Comment: ya the package seems ok, it looks like MDC is the way to go, just trying to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

Can it be that when you load via properties the `AppServerPatternLayout` is instantiated before the `AppServerLoggerFactory` is created? If you pick up the values of your custom fields at creation as opposed to at first use that could be an explanation.

Comment: AppServerPatternLayour doesn't have a dependency on AppServerLoggerFactory. All its doing is creating a AppServerPatternParser which is then checking if its getting an instanceof AppServerLoggingEvent using its properties

Comment: @Scott, Your logger has a default value for the static factory with `null`'s as values. If the event is created from that factory the values will be empty. You can prove/disprove by moving the `.configure()` after you instantiate your custom factory. I beleive what you see is a race condition between creation of your factory and the event object.

Comment: you may be right, when I switched back to a PatternLayout in the properties it showed the %h in the log. so it must have been loading.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that you will achieve this with properties configuration, but I think you can do this with XML, which gives you a lot of customization options:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration
  xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
  debug="true"
  reset="true"
>
  <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <layout class="your.package.AppServerPatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="YOUR CONVERSION PATTERN"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
  </root>

  <loggerFactory class="your.package.AppServerLoggerFactory">
    <param name="server" value="MyServer"/>
    <param name="component" value="MyComponent"/>
    <param name="version" value="1.0r"/>
  </loggerFactory>

</log4j:configuration>
```

You will need to define setters on `AppServerLoggerFactory` for server, component and version.  Also, read `log4j.dtd` on general layout of xml configuration file.

Save this file as log4j.xml and define -Dlog4j.configuration=/path/to/log4j.xml in your startup script, or replace log4j.properties with log4j.xml in your web-app.

I've never tried a custom LoggerFactory before, but it may be that because it is installed by the configurator you can use standard `getLogger` factory calls, e.g.

```
//Logger logger = AppServerLogger.getLogger("some.log");
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("some.log");
```